# Change CSS on a-tag when hash appears in URL

Tags: css, hash

I have a fixed navigation bar with an **a-tag** that links to a hash-URL. When the **a-tag** is clicked the URL changes from **url.com** to **url.com/#all** and the page scrolls down to a div with the belonging id, while the navigation bar still appears as it is fixed.

What I want is to style the **a-tag** when the **#all** appears in the URL. All without refreshing the page. I guess it can be done quite simple with jQuery, but I'm not sure how.

To simplify what I want it is this:

**Without #all in the URL:**

`<div style="position:fixed;height:50px;width:100%;">
      <a href="#all">All</a>
</div>`

**With #all in the URL:**

`<div style="position:fixed;height:50px;width:100%;">
      <a href="#all" style="font-weight:700;">All</a>
</div>`

This also implies that when the #all is removed again from the URL the style should be removed as well - again, all without refreshing the page.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: No, I am not using bootstrap.

Comment: Then see my answer below. Kindly accept if work for you.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want to change the style of the link once it has been clicked. That can be done easily with css:

```
a:visited {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

I would advise giving a class or an id to your link though, so that the style doesn't apply to all of them!

If you reeeeally want to us jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('a').css("font-weight", "700");
})
```

If you actually want to use the url, try :

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://url.com/#all')
    $('a').css("font-weight", "700");
```

My only concern is with the http/https, but that should be easily handled with an OR condition or some regex on the url variable to get a better substring.

Comment: Thanks for your time! The problem with the a:visited is that it will stay bold all the time after it has been clicked once, which it shouldn't as you can also click on other links on the page without loading a new page. Regarding the jQuery solution the problem is that it is based on when you click on the link and not when the #all appears in the url..  There is also another link linking #all, so therefore it should be controlled by the URL and not whether you click the link. Makes sense?

Comment: Makes perfect sense! Didn't get why you wanted that after reading your first post, but your comment made it clearer. Let me try something.

Comment: @JEP I updated my answer with a new function that could probably also be used on click if your page doesn't load on the #all anchor by default. Tell me if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `#` value from the url using just `JavaScript`

```
var id = window.location.hash.substr(1);
```

Now you have the value after the `#`, you can then use it as a `selector`.

***So, for example;***

```
/**
 * Lets say the URL looks like this:
 * https://example.com#all
 * var id contains now the value `all`
 */
var id = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    /**
     * Update id to valid css id selector
     * id is now `#all`
     */
    id = "#" + id;
/**
 * Get the element using the id we created above
 */
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+ id +'"]')[0];
    /**
     * You can also change the font weight using JavaScript
     */
    elem.style.fontWeight = "700";
```

***See demo below;***

```js
/**
 * Lets say the URL looks like this:
 * https://example.com#all
 * var id contains now the value `all`
 */
var id = "all" //(Lets asume the value is `all`)window.location.hash.substr(1);
  /**
   * Update id to valid css id selector
   * id is now `#all`
   */
  id = "#" + id;
/**
 * Get the element using the id we created above
 */
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="'+ id +'"]')[0];
 /**
   * You can also change the font weight using JavaScript
   */
 elem.style.fontWeight = "700";
```

```html
<a href="#all">TEST</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work although the problem is that it doesn't change immediately to `font-weight:700`. I have to update the page while **#all** appears in the url in order to get the css change. Also there seems to be the problem that even without a hash in the url (just **example.com**) an a tag linking to just **#** seems to be styled font-weight:700.

Comment: You need to check if the url changes. So wrap the code inside a function. Most likely its a `click` function in your case

Comment: Oh, and you have to check ofcourse if the `#` isset in the url. Else just leave it empty. Thats why all links with `href="#"` are getting bold. The above example is just a simple demo.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then use [built-in bootstrap scrollspy](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp). Otherwise use [this fiddle code to create your own](https://jsfiddle.net/up4nu/6713/). Modify the code as per need

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```